# Topology of level surfaces

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

I have a level surface of the form $f(x,y,z,w)=0$  and also $g(x,y,z)=0$.

Here f and g are differentiable!

I need to decide if they are *compact* or not.

Is there any criteria, theorem or anything?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In the topology of $\mathbb{R^n}$ we need for the function to be closed and bounded. The latter seems to be free since you are on a level surface i.e $f(X)=c$.

Comment: The preimage of $\{0\}$ is always closed, but doesn't have to be bounded. Consider for example $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ for $f(x, y, z) = x$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g:\mathbb {R} ^3 \to \mathbb R$ by $g(x,y,z)=x$.  Then the surface described by $g=0$ is just the $yz$-plane, which is not compact in $\mathbb R^3$ as it is not bounded.  The criterion you are after is the Heine-Borel Theorem, which says a subset of $\mathbb R ^n$ is compact $\iff$ it is closed and bounded.

Comment: Ok...I think that continuous functions pull back closed set to closed sets. Then a level set of a continuous function is closed. However it is not always bounded.

Comment: not sure what you mean by a level set, but basically closed and bounded are independent of one-another... you cannot get compactness without verifying both.